# NetBeans cannot find my Maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I have created a Maven project, and have added my required dependencies. When I attempt to build the project, I get the following errors:

[image]

My dependencies do show that the `org.apache.poi` library is there:

[image]

Which includes the requisite packages:

[image]

Here are my includes:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
```

I'm relatively new to Java, and very new to Maven, but when I right click on
`Dependencies` and `Add Dependency`, I enter the appropriate groupID and ArtifactID and version, ([as listed in Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.poi%7Cpoi%7C3.16%7Cjar)) and it automatically downloads the file. Not sure what else I'm missing. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I should note that I also tried Manually installing artifact and got the same result.

Edit: Here's the dependency section of my `pom.xml` file. I'm curious why maven only added two, when I have many more libs, but that seems to be another issue. POI is listed here and it's the one that the compiler is complaining about.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Please post your code for ConvertXLSXtoCSV and your pom.xml

Comment: The rest of the code really doesn't have much to do with the issue.. this is more of a maven issue. I will update with the pom.xml contents though.

Comment: Does your compilation error reference one of your import lines?  Or does your compiler get past your imports?

Comment: The errors are on the import lines, that's the entire issue. The import lines are the ones referenced in the error messages. (Lines 7-11)

Comment: It's not an issue with the configuration you have posted.  What IDE are you using?  I have a strong suspicion the issue has to do with your build path.  If you let me know what IDE you are using I can have you verify that your dependencies reside within your buildpath.  What you have posted thus far is correct although in a few instances is inconsistent (for example the link you posted does not contain both POI components you have as dependencies)

Comment: sorry i didnt see you posted netbeans. give me a minute

Comment: I'm almost positive it's a problem with my build path. My thought is that Maven (since I added the dependencies via Maven) would take care of that. As the title says, I'm using NetBeans. (Version 8.2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147474/discussion-between-christopher-maggiulli-and-tim-s).

Comment: Do you see commons-codec and commons-collection in your dependencies as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution, as odd and site-specific as it is, is still the solution. Basically here's the situation:  I'm working at a company where the normal developers all use Windows for their development environments. They have specific configurations that allow them to punch through the corporate proxy so they can get to external maven repositories, configurations that not everyone else has. Because of this, tools like Eclipse (the normal IDE here) was not able to download through the proxy. Being a former Linux sysadmin, I was able to get the proxy issues resolved using NetBeans in a Linux VM. The issue, however was that all of the maven configs that I used were based in windows, and this is what I finally fixed in my settings.xml file:

```
<localRepository>c:\.m2\repository</localRepository>
```

should have been

```
<localRepository>.m2/repository</localRepository>
```

in Linux. Once I noticed that, and changed the settings (and directory name) it worked flawlessly every time. Thanks to all who responded.

Answer (score 2):

#### Missing information

There is no error with the configurations you have posted thus far in my environment.  I have a feeling it has to do with your class path and/or Netbeans *Non-classpath dependencies* however I cannot be sure because I do not have the necessary visibility into your project.  Did the GUI add the `<type>` element to your POM.xml?

Therefore instead of trying to uncover the issue you are experiencing via question and answer I will posted a standard way to set up this project for you to compare against.

#### Create new project

1. Go to *File*
2. *New Project*
3. Categories *Maven*
4. Projects *Java Application*

You will get the following screen.

[image: New Java Application]

1. #### Leave the defaults as they stand for now and click finish. Your project should now have the following structure

[image]

2. #### Right click on the dependency folder and click Add Dependency.  Enter the following information.

[image]

3. #### Do the following again with this information

[image]

4. #### Your project should now look like this

[image]

5. #### Create a new class by going to File, New File, Java Class

[image]

6. #### Enter the following code/

Do you see a red line under your import?

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;
import org.apache.poi.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Right click on your project, clean and build.  Does it generate an error?  If so can you post your console?

Comment: So here's the strange thing. I went through the instructions just as you listed them, but used the default "NewClass" classname. I got an error saying that org.apache.poi didn't exist. I went through and changed the class name (and the file name) to Main/Main.java, and it then built successfully.

Comment: To try to reproduce this error, I changed back the two things (file name and class name) back to "NewClass.java" and "NewClass" respectively, and did a clean-and-build, and it errored again. Now it errors every time. Perhaps the first time not cleaning had something to do with it? Either way I'm stumped.

Comment: What JDK are you using?  Is there a red line under your import statements or are you getting the error only when you clean and build?  Can you post the entire console for me?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes Netbeans gets confused as you are editing the pom and doesn't download from maven. Simply do a "clean and build" of your project and it will download the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `import org.apache.*;` and remove all your manual imports. Just in case...

Furthermore, make sure that you're using dependency info from this [site](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.16)

I did a test from Eclipse with your dependency, using Maven clean configuration and run successfully

Comment: Tried importing `org.apache.*`, `org.apache.poi.*`, and `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*` and all had the same effect, "does not exist' is the error. (Also with commenting out other poi imports.)

Comment: did you try to use version 3.15 or 3.14?

Comment: No -- this isn't a code issue, it's saying it can't even find the libraries, even though they auto-downloaded via Maven. I can try that though.

Comment: [for ubuntu] When Maven successfully builds a project, its dependencies are saved in a hidden folder named .m2 (or something) at your home directory. Maybe you can check where your dependencies-jars are stored

Comment: They are in ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/poi